# author archives, showing all custom post types, problem on pagination

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop, archives

Please, [look at the link to the page I need support with](https://gialloecucina.com/author/mbaldi/).

This is a website where several “authors” make their reviews on books or create some original posts. This page shows “Badges” which are all about different custom post types made by the author “mbaldi” in the link. A custom post type is “Rubrica originale”, another “libri da leggere” and so on…

I did with using Elementor pro, in particular a post loop widget with a wp query (query id) for retrieving various custom post types. Everything looks fine.

What it does not work and I am becoming crazy is the pagination. Now you see pagination disabled, this author has actually hundreds of posts and if I enable pagination in post loop, page 1 is shown correctly. When I click 2, 3 and so on… I receive error 404.

I read a lot about this and I understand this is due to the fact I did it with “archive” pages… but I do not know how to solve it. is there anybody here who can help me with this? I am not very expert but maybe you have some tricky way to do it…

Thanks.

Mario.